# pulling all columns with certain values

Tags: sas

I am working with a huge dataset in sas trying to use proc sql and I need help setting up a like statement. I'm trying to extract all the columns that have 'eco' in the name

I'm getting an error in the where statement as it is not registering the second *.
Any help?

proc sql
select *
from cfy19e8
where * LIKE %eco%;

Comment: Do you want to retrieve all observations and only certain columns or all columns and only certain observations ?

Comment: Like works on observation values not column names. If you want all columns that have eco in the name you need to use a different approach.

Comment: Please explain more about what you are doing.  Currently it is not clear if you are asking to pick variables ("columns") or observations ("rows").  And neither one really makes that much sense.  Perhaps if you explain what you are trying to do someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate all of your columns with `catx()` and find any one that has the word `eco`.

```
data have;
    input col1$ col2$ col3$;
    datalines;
sadfeco kdoa wrfs
asdf asdf sadf
mfecosa mawoeco mfzeco
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    where catx('|', col1, col2, col3) LIKE '%eco%';
run;
```

If you have a lot of character columns, you could use the shortcut `_CHARACTER_` to concatenate all variables, then use `find()` within an `if` statement in a data step.

```
data want;
    set have;
    if(find(catx('|', of _CHARACTER_), 'eco') );
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
proc contents noprint data=cfy19e8 out=eco_columns(where=(upcase(name) like '%ECO%'));
run;
title 'Columns with ECO in their name';
proc print data=eco_columns;
  var name;
run;
```